# vbs read text file line by line and split it with comma

Tags: vbscript, line-by-line

has a text file with this contain

> name1,21
>   name2,33
>   name4,22

how do i read and store this in other variable for example

```
name= name1
age= 21
```

print out this and loop until end of this file

print out will be

> name: name1 is 21 years old

this is what i have tried but the message box i get are blank

```
Const ForReading = 1 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\my.txt", ForReading) 

strOutput = ""

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline 
    arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , ";")

    If (UBound(arrServiceList) >= 6) Then
        strOutput = strOutput & "name: " & arrServiceList(0) & ", age: " & arrServiceList(6) & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop 

WScript.Echo strOutput
```

all I'm getting is a blank box

Comment: You are splitting on `;` but your text has `,`.

Comment: Once you have resolved the `split` issue mentioned above, your array `arrServiceList` will only contain 2 elements (unless you've provided a cut down version of the file and there are more data elements on each line), so referencing `arrServiceList(6)` will cause an array failure.

Answer (score 0):

finally managed to get it work, just sharing, below are my code:

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filename = "C:\my.txt"
listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll
listLines = Split(listFile, vbCrLf)

i = 0

For Each line In listLines
Dim arr
arr = Split(line,",")
WScript.Echo CStr(i) + " Name: " + arr(1)+ " age: "+arr(0)
Next
```

not sure if this is the best solution, anyone got better ? 
first i split it line by line, then from that line i split it by comma